# Bind Buttons to ScrollWheel and Keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, button, scroll, key-bindings

In my application I have a `Previous Button` and a `Next Button`. When they are clicked, a particular function is called with different parameters.

I was wondering if there was a way that the `Mouse ScrollWheel` and the `Left` and `Right` keyboard keys could be bound to have the same result as clicking on these two `Buttons`?

I.E Pushing upwards on the `ScrollWheel` or Pressing the `Right Key` on the keyboard would be tantamount to clicking the `Next Button` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attached Behaviors](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF). Create a behavior with command and parameter properties and bind. In the property changed just hook on needed events. Like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/478643/Mouse-Event-Commands-for-MVVM) for MouseUp.

For the left and right key you could do it like this:

```
    <Grid.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Left" Command="{Binding ExecutePreviousCommand}" />
        <KeyBinding Key="Right" Command="{Binding ExecuteNextCommand}" />
    </Grid.InputBindings>
```